# How to create a tablespace with Python cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I have this script:

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid)
db = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, dsn_tns, mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
cursor = db.cursor()
SQL = """CREATE SMALLFILE TABLESPACE "TBDDATA7"
                 DATAFILE
                'D:\Oracle\OracleData\Data\Data7' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 100M
                LOGGING
                DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS
                ONLINE
                EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
                SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;    
        """ 
result = cursor.execute(SQL)
```

and its always returning the same error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02180:invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong

I would appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The wrong thing was the semicolon at the end of the SQL string.